# use variables from out side function laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

i have resource controller 
and inside the resource controller the index function

```
public function index()
{
    //
}
```

now i want to use variable from out side the function 
like this

```
public $data = "data";
public function index() use ($data)
{
    return $data;
}
```

i gat this error

```
syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting ';' or '{'
```

i tried it as function like this

```
public function data()
{
    $data = "data";
    return $data;
}
public function index() use (data)
{

}
```

i gat the same error

```
syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE), expecting ';' or '{'
```

so how can i access variable and function from outside the function ..

Comment: You need to access like this: $this->data

Comment: thanks man its works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `this` to access to the variable:

```
public $data = "data";

public function index()
{
    return $this->data;
}
```